# Where to get Flexunit 4.x?

Tags: actionscript-3, flexunit4

I need flexunit4.x, anyone please give me a working url for where to download it, also any tutorials URL would be very great.

From my online search, all pages lead to flexunit.org, which doesn't seem to work any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it from (its 4.1)
https://github.com/flexunit/flexunit

Example
http://www.stasha.info/index.php?id=106
http://asmock.sourceforge.net/wiki/Template:FlexUnit_4.1_Example

may this will help you